# How to create an audio Playlist in C# , Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, mediaelement, playlist

```
private async void Set_Up_Media_Player()
{
    var Location = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    var Folder = await Location.GetFolderAsync("Music");
    this._Start = await Folder.GetFileAsync("start.wav");
    this._Loop = await Folder.GetFileAsync("loop.wav");
    this._Stream = await _Start.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

    _Music = new MediaElement() { AutoPlay = true, IsLooping = false };
    _Music.SetSource(_Stream, _Start.ContentType);
    _Music.MediaEnded += Music_MediaEnded;

    this._Stream = await _Loop.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
}

void Music_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Music.SetSource(this._Stream, this._Loop.ContentType);
    Music.IsLooping = true;
}
```

I'm trying to get the MediaElement `_Music` To first play the `_Start` song then transition into the second `_Loop` song. I have tried adding an event Handler `Music_MediaEnded` but the `_Start` song ends and the event is never called.

How do I create a playlist so that the MediaElement will automatically transition to the next song?

Comment: How it worked for the _Music  and then _Start ?

Answer (score 0):

As the media ends in the handler set the AutoPlay property of the MediaElement true.
i.e., after setting a new source write

Music.AutoPlay=true;

Comment: So in the `Music_MediaEnded(...)` after `SetSource(..)` I would then set `Musice.AutoPlay = true;`